# JAVASCRIPT display full day after getting short day from datas.date

Tags: javascript, date, format

I have this code that gets each day from datas.date in a for-loop. The day format it gets is short (Sun, Mon, Tue). Is it possible that I display it in a table in long? (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday) Here is the code.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < datas.date.length; i++) {
                //daily turn in rate for selected week
                week2.push(datas.valueIn[i]);
                eachDay = datas.date[i];
                totalVisitor = datas.valueIn[i];
                if(totalVisitor > highest)
                    highest = totalVisitor;

                $("#tableMonthlyTrend").find('tbody')
                    .append($('<tr>')
                        .append($('<td class="tableContentDay">')
                        .text(eachDay)                                
                        )
                        .append($('<td class="tableContent">')
                            .text(totalVisitor)
                        )    
                        .append($('<td class="tableContent">')
                            .text(datas.lastValueIn[i])
                        )
                    );
                }
```

Comment: Well there a 7 days.. so you could just use an object as a look up table.

Comment: @NickBailey Nick can you write an example? I am still new in this thingy. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is use an object to map from short to long. That can become cumbersome if you're dealing with multiple languages. For English-only, however, you could define this mapping:

```
var dayShortToLong = {
    Mon: "Monday",
    Tue: "Tuesday",
    Wed: "Wednesday",
    Thu: "Thursday",
    Fri: "Friday",
    Sat: "Saturday",
    Sun: "Sunday"
};
```

Then in your function, change the line

```
eachDay = datas.date[i];
```

to use the mapping, like this

```
eachDay = dayShortToLong[datas.date[i]] || "Bad day";
```